# JSON Parsing error with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, swift

I'm new in iOS programming and I'm trying with the new language Swift.
I've a problem / I don't know how in parsing JSON with Swift for iOS use. I already used JSON in Android, so I know that the JSON and the link is right, but when I try the code below (seen in a tutorial) the app seems to crash and highlighted this line:

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
```

The console gives me back this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.) fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is the entire code of the button's action:

```
let urlAsString = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.altervista.org/App/_DD_/downloadutenti.php?email="+campoEmail.text+"&password="+campoPassword.text
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    println(url)
    println(urlSession)
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        if(data != nil){
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary


        if (err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

            var jsonEmail = ""
            if var jsonEmail: String! = jsonResult["email"] as? NSString{

            }
            else{
                println("PROBLEM 1")
            }

            var jsonPassword = ""
            if var jsonPassword: String! = jsonResult["pass"] as? NSString{

            }
            else{
                println("PROBLEM 2")
            }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.scritta2.text = "Email: " + jsonEmail + " - Password: " + jsonPassword
        })
    }
    })
    jsonQuery.resume()
```

N.B.
I use xcode6 simulator and I know for sure that the "variables" campoEmail.text and campoPassword.text are taken in a good way.

JSON it should give back:

```
[{"id":"1","email":"lincoln@gmail.com","password":"pass","permessi":"1","stato":"Italia","citta":"Palermo","via":"Via Lincoln, 29","cap":"90100","telefono":"091xxxxxx"}]
```

**EDIT FOR @Neo HELP:**
I edited all the action of the button like this, but the code goes to the data's null check..

```
let curURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://fantacharleston.altervista.org/App/_DD_/downloadutenti.php?email=lincoln@gmail.com&password=pass")!
        let curRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: curURL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(curRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData?, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (data != nil) {
                if let jsonArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray? {

                    let jsonObject: NSDictionary? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDictionary
                    if (jsonObject != nil) {
                        NSLog("object: %@", jsonObject!)
                        let email: NSString? = jsonObject?.objectForKey("email") as? NSString
                        let password: NSString? = jsonObject?.objectForKey("password") as? NSString

                        if (email != nil && password != nil) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                self.scritta2.text = "Email: " + email! + " - Password: " + password!
                            })
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            else{
                println("null")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide me a part of the JSON you try to parse?

Comment: You should, as matter of course, include the entire error message you received.

Comment: I added what it should give back. @Neo

Comment: @HotLicks can you say me how to read it? I know how to do it on eclipse, not in xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think I know where your Problem is... Your are trying to put a JSONArray into a NSDictionary... That cant go... Its like trying to put it into a JSONObject in Java.

Just exchange the NSDictionary with NSArray and be sure to get properties like array[0]["key"], not like array["key"], because you are working with an array, not with a dictionary... (Its like ArrayList, and HashMap in Java)

Try this please...

```
if let jsonResult: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSArray? {

let jsonEmail: NSString? = jsonResult.objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("email")

}
```

**Edit with Code you need**

Here it is... I wrote it a bit like I would write it in Java for Android... I think you will easily get it... The problem you commented maybe was that there is no "pass" tag in your JSON... its "password"...

```
let curURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://fantacharleston.altervista.org/App/_DD_/downloadutenti.php?email=lincoln@gmail.com&password=pass")!
        let curRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: curURL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(curRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData?, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (data != nil) {
                if let jsonArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray? {

                    let jsonObject: NSDictionary? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDictionary
                    if (jsonObject != nil) {
                        NSLog("object: %@", jsonObject!)
                        let email: NSString? = jsonObject?.objectForKey("email") as? NSString
                        let password: NSString? = jsonObject?.objectForKey("password") as? NSString

                        if (email != nil && password != nil) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                self.scritta2.text = "Email: " + email + " - Password: " + password
                            })
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Neo !
Well it was a veeeeeery good help, because the app didn't crash now, but it returns empty values.

The link that returns the JSON is it:
http://fantacharleston.altervista.org/App/_DD_/downloadutenti.php?email=lincoln@gmail.com&password=pass

can you help me please? Is something wrong with the "array[0]["key"]"/"array["key"]"?

P.S.
The debug says me: "JSON Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

Comment: Ok, give me ten minutes, I will "wire" you something together that will solve your problem...

Comment: Sure, have fun with it... If it doesn't help you, just write me a line... :-)

Comment: Hey @Neo, thank you for the code, it's more readable for me, but it doesn't enter in (data != nil), because data is nil.. something is wrong with the connection. Isn't something because i'm on the simulator, right?

Comment: Hmm no, I have "tested" this code in XCode, also on Simulator... My code ran through and was ok... Have you used it conpletly? Because it should replace the complete code you have posted

Comment: I changed the post to answer to you. Anyway yes, as you can see, now I use only the code you posted, there is something wrong with "data.."

Comment: The only different thing is the "!" at the end of the var email and password (XCode wanted it)

Comment: Hmm I have just copied the code (my version you postet in your question edit) from your post edit into xcode, pressed play and it went through on simulator and showed me the object, as well as the email and password in NSLog.... There was no error happening...

Comment: Also the email! mark is right... Its to unwrap the optional to its value

Comment: mm no i didn't solve the problem, the connection don't go.. thank you anyway for your help

Comment: yes, Im sorry... the problem is the code above is working, even after copy/pasting your edit of my code to my XCode, so its not possible for me to get this bug, because it doesn't appear on my tests... sorry...